# How to find div Element without an id attribute with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using C# and Selenium Webdriver and I'm trying to find a `div` Element in my html code which looks like this:

```
<div class="x-grid-cell-inner" style="text-align: left;" unselectable="on">
    phys_tag_desc
</div>
```

I cant find a method to search for the value of the `div` Element with Selenium Webdriver. I already searched this site and checked the Selenium Webdriver Documentation, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: So what's unique about the `div`?

Comment: Have you tried using xpath?? **//div[@class='x-grid-cell-inner']**

Comment: Thank you for your response. The Problem is there isnt anything unique about the div Element. There are more div Elements with class='x-grid-cell-inner. The only thing unique is the text value and i don't know how to search for it.

Comment: Well show us some of the HTML you are dealing with, so we can see the structure of the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well if text value is unique, then solution is simple. Try the xpath below:

```
//div[text()='phys_tag_desc']
```

If the text is not exact match. Try following:

```
//div[contains(text(),'phys_tag_desc')]
```

Answer (score 2):

I have two ways. 
Way 2 is more complex but more effective.

Way 1;

You can loop in all divs and look for some equals

Example:

```
foreach(HtmlElement o in webbrowser.Document.GetElementByTagName("div"))
{
    HtmlElement yourElement;
    if(o.GetAttribute("class")=="x-grid-cell-inner"&&o.GetAttribute("style")=="text-align: left;")
    {
        yourElement=o;
        break;
    }
    DoSomethingWith(yourElememt);
}
```

The other way is follow elements path;
You can find the closer element that has a ID
Example:

```
<div id="element">
    <div>content..</div>
    <div>
        <div class="x-grid-cell-inner" style="text-align: left;" unselectable="on">
        phys_tag_desc
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The closest element that have id on this example is

```
<div id="element">
```

your element's parent is 2. children of id="element" div
You can get it and follow path like this

```
yourElement = webbrowser.Document.GetElementById("element").Children[1].Children[0];
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try Solution 1 but I'm not too happy with it. Solution 2 wont work because all other Elements in my html code change their id values each time you call the page.

Comment: @user3292642 If elements html path is not changing you can follow them from the <body> tag like this: webbrowser.Document.GetElementByTagName("body")[0].Children[0].Children[8].... too long but too effective.

Answer (score 0):

In other situation you can use the **XPATH** Boolean operators. 
Try the **xpath** below:

```
By.XPath("//div[contains(@class,'*x-grid-cell-inner*') and contains(@unselectable, '*on*') and contains(text(),'*phys_tag_desc*')]")
```

Bye